# How do I know what time my reputation cap criterion will be reset?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [What Time Zone do the SO servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-the-so-servers-operate-in)

Hi,

I would like to know how does a day is counted in stackoverflow. Is it my local time or it is GMT or PST. The reason behind this question is if my reputation cap ends for a day, I would like to know at what time the next day starts.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-the-so-servers-operate-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOFU uses UTC time. You can view the current time on your ["recent"/replies page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/252398):

> all times are in UTC; the current time is 2010-03-28 04:25:18Z