# What time is it in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, timestamps, timezone

Is there a global timer for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Hold your cursor over the "asked 4 mins ago" above your name.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-the-so-servers-operate-in

Comment: @mmyers - are you suggesting I should ask a new question each time I want to know the SO time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses [UTC time](http://www.google.ca/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=UTC+Time&btnG=Google+Search).

Comment: Clear and short!