# Timezone of stackoverflow data

Tags: discussion, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What time zone do SO's servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in)

I wonder under which timezone the time information is stored in stackoverflow database, for example in the column posts.creationdate?

EDIT

I am playing with https://data.stackexchange.com/ , where I can see directly into the data in stackoverflow database. That's why I ask the timezone of the data *in the database* instead of timezone that is displayed.

Comment: Pretty sure it's straight UTC time.. but I'll wait for someone to verify that

Comment: @Dori so you are saying that the time in the database is ALSO in UTC? Because time display can be different from how it is stored.

Comment: Why is it relevant how it's stored? The display time is all that matters, right?

Comment: @Cody because I'm playing with http://data.stackexchange.com/, looking directly into the data without any interfaces.

Comment: Re your edit; a: that isn't exactly "directly", but more importantly b: the times are *still* UTC.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the confirmation