# Is reputation-per-day being miscalculated?

Tags: support, reputation, timestamps, timezone

At first, I thought that the timezone the servers were located in may be UTC, but from other MetaSO questions I see that [the servers are located in NYC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42179/194328).

[This question seems to indicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99859/194328) that the clock *on the servers* is set to UTC.

Is this the reason why reputation seems to have a display error?  See the image below.  "*Today*" I received some `+2` reps, for mods done "*13 hours ago*"...... but 13hr ago was 9/10/2013 for me, not 9/11/2013.

---

*note; all these little reps are tag-cleanup that I'm doing.*

[image: 13hr ago was not "today" for me]

Comment: currently it is 14:09 UTC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are using UTC time here. You can see it in the topbar

[image: UTC]

So 13 hours ago was today.