# Posted question shows wrong origination date : yesterday is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, posting, dates

I posted a question 
([How do I read ERD Notation (crow's feet) to convert to Natural Language?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129551/how-do-i-read-erd-notation-crows-feet-to-convert-to-natural-language))
on Wednesday, 02/17/2015, but it is showing that I asked the question "yesterday".
All of the comments I posted on Wednesday also show up as being posted "yesterday".

In my current timezone (EST) it is currently 8:45am Friday 02/19/2015.

This may sound a bit nit-picky that I'm submitting this question but I'm curious about why it is showing up this way.  I understand that "yesterday" could be interpreted loosely.

I went back to the note I posted and I see that floating over the date does show that it was 02/17 when I posted (2 days ago).

This was interesting because it almost had me convinced that I had written this up just yesterday.  The days blur together.  :)

[image: date tooltip]

Comment: Timezones, maybe?

Comment: Right. Could be timezone problem. I posted and read from the same timezone so I'm not sure.  Maybe related to timezone server is in.  Not sure.

Comment: It works off of the utc time zone. Your day resets at 7 pm, mine resets at 4 pm (PST)

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127668/yesterday-time-specification-shown-when-it-was-actually-the-day-before-yesterd

Comment: @m0sa any reason for not closing as duplicate?