# StackOverflow timestamp?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What time zone do SO's servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in)

I was looking at my previous questions, and was just wondering what time of day I had asked them. The times  I'm seeing don't make much sense as to when I'd be on the computer, so does anyone know what Time Zone the timestamps are for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow operates in [Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (UTC). So the time that is reflected on the site is offset from you depending on what time zone you live/work in and whether you observe [Daylight Saving Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

This causes a lot of confusion, especially for people far away from the date line trying to get badges that relate to consecutive days etc.

Answer (score 0):

The information regarding the timezone for any of the [stackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) sites can be seen when hovering at user's name at the site header.

> [image]